# Error passing NSNumber to UInt32

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnumber, uint32

I am trying to pass a NSNumber into a UInt32 variable, it seems to work but when I go to log the UInt32's value I get stuck.

this is what my code looks like.

```
if ([methodName isEqualToString:@"Manu"]) {
        cacheNumber = [cacheValue objectForKey:@"Manus"];

        NSLog(@"%@", cacheNumber); // This produces the correct number
    }

    UInt32 CACHE_VALUE = [cacheNumber intValue];
    NSLog(@"%@", CACHE_VALUE); // This is where my thread gets stuck
```

This is the message that it produces when I try to step through the second NSLog (as I have breakpoints on both logs to check their output).

> Single stepping until exit from function objc_msgSend,  which has no
>   line number information.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The problem is in your NSLog.  CACHE_VALUE isn't an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You print a NSString not a UInt.

```
    NSLog(@"%lu", CACHE_VALUE); // This is where my thread gets stuck
```

Comment: ohh crap.. I should have seen that.. my bad. what a noob. thank you.

Comment: will accept your answer shortly. actualy just tried this in xcode, it told me to use @"%lu",... so I updated your solution

Answer (score 0):

As you're logging an integer and not an object, ie. an NSString, you should use the %d (decimal) placeholder instead of %@ (object).

```
NSLog(@"Value: %d", CACHE_VALUE);
```